# Help identify this IC (voltage regulator?)

Tags: voltage-regulator

While reversing an old made in Russia power supply I had found these ICs. Here I am attach the circuit I had drawn and the components. The VCC and other power symbols are my assumptions. 16-pin SOIC is 26A14, maybe a transistor array?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You forgot about attaching the schematics.

Comment: If you are not sure that it is a semiconductor: It MIGHT also be a shunt resistor with two additional connectors for voltage drop measurement and two connectors for a built-in temperature sensor.

Comment: The symbols on it appear to indicate that it is a bridge rectifier.

Comment: Could it be an HEMT?

Comment: Please go on your reverse engineering and draw a draft schematic (at least a small portion of the whole circuit). Draw this component as a 4-pin-box and show the surrounding components with connections. Then we can guess what it is and its purpose.

Comment: As iam new to this site, i was unable to upload 2 images. Now Iam adding another post with the schematic. Thanking you.

Comment: @srinivasT Don't. This is discuraged. Link to the image and someone with more points can edit and add the image for you.

Comment: I've added your schematic and other picture to this question.  Please delete the other question.

Comment: I really doubt that the 26A14 is a transistor array.  That looks to be some kind of switching regulator for a switch mode power supply.

Comment: What a gorgeous military-style hermetic packages those are!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Producer of 26A14 is [TEF](http://www.npptez.ru/) in Tomilino, of 26A22 is Kremniy from Bryansk. I am afraid it is military design, and you may not be able to find datasheets for the devices. However you can try registering on TEF's site and see if it will give you access to its library.

Comment: Thank you very much. At last i could able to find the manufacturer. I will login into TEF. Anyway 12A22 info still not available. Thank you once again.